# Table package in R

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to make a table one which shows the average value for the continuous variable (x) across subgroups. Most table one packages are for frequency tables and treat my variable x as a categorical value and fill in the table with the frequency of observations in each subgroup for a given x value. Any suggestions on a table package that will accomplish what I need.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `library(vtable)`. Check the link for more information about this package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vtable/vignettes/sumtable.html

Here I will give you an example of a summary table showing the average value for continuous variables across subgroups, first the data:

```
d <- read.table(text=
                  'Name     Month  Rate1     Rate2
Aira       1      12        23
Aira       2      18        73
Aira       3      19        45
Ben        1      53        19
Ben        2      22        87
Ben        3      19        45
Cat        1      22        87
Cat        2      67        43
Cat        3      45        32', header=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
  Name Month Rate1 Rate2
1 Aira     1    12    23
2 Aira     2    18    73
3 Aira     3    19    45
4  Ben     1    53    19
5  Ben     2    22    87
6  Ben     3    19    45
7  Cat     1    22    87
8  Cat     2    67    43
9  Cat     3    45    32
```

I want to group the names and check there average values for the variables using this code:

```
install.packages("vtable")
library(vtable)
sumtable(d, group = "Name")
```

This is the output:

[image]

You can do so many things with this package, so I would suggest to have a look at the this one.